# Sending $_POST variable AND $_FILE variable to a .php using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, upload

I need for some reasons to add an ajax image uploading system to my website. (I don't want to refresh the page ... )

Some jquery plugins were pretty good, but i'm storing the images on my server by id, and i can't tell my server (using these plugins) which id it has to use. So i need a way to send my server an int var ($id) which tell the upload.php file (which is receiving the $_FILE var) where it should store the Image file.

Comment: try this [Ajax Multiple file upload script with Progress bar, Drag and Drop](http://lesson8.blogspot.in/2012/09/ajax-multiple-file-upload-script-with.html)

Comment: It won't work since i can't send to my server the $id i want him to use ... :/

Comment: First of all, `$id` is a PHP variable. You can send your PHP scripts anything using AJAX, or call a PHP script with a link and POST or GET parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's okay guys, i used the $_SESSION variable so i can tell on which id i am :D Thanks anyway